# SwiftUI + Decoding Yelp API Response

Tags: json, swift, swiftui, yelp-fusion-api

I'm new to working with Swift and JSON, I'll try to describe what I'm trying to accomplish as best as I can.

I'm trying to access the Yelp API service and return and decode the JSON results and display the results in a list.

I've successfully been able to hit the API and log the results to the console, but I haven't been able to map the results to UI elements to display within a view.

Below is the struct for the results and the view I'm attempting to display the results in. I'm returning the error from my load function after the view loads.

Data.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct BusinessesResponse: Codable {
    let restaurants: [RestaurantResponse]
}

struct RestaurantResponse: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: String
    var name: String
    var coordinates: [longlat]
    var is_closed: Bool
    var category: String
    var imageURL: URL
    var url: URL
    var review_count: Int
   var rating: Double
   var display_phone: String
   var distance: Double
}
```

ContentView

```
import SwiftUI
import YelpAPI
import Combine
import CoreLocation

struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject private var locationManager = LocationManager()
    @ObservedObject var fetcher = RestaurantFetcher()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(fetcher.businesses) { restaurant in
                VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(restaurant.name)
                }
              }
           }
        }
    }

    struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            ContentView()
    }
}
```

```
public class RestaurantFetcher: ObservableObject {
    @Published var businesses = [RestaurantResponse]()
    
    init() {
        load(latitude: 28.4293403, longitude: -81.6241764)
    }
    
    func load(latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {
         let apikey = "API-KEY-HERE"
        let url = URL(string: "https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?latitude=\(latitude)&longitude=\(longitude)")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.setValue("Bearer \(apikey)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            do {
                if let d = data {
                    let decodedLists = try JSONDecoder().decode([RestaurantResponse].self, from: d)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.businesses = decodedLists
                    }
                } else {
                    print("No Data")
                }
            } catch {
                print ("Caught")
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

JSON response from Yelp's API

```
{
    "businesses": [
        {
            "id": "ZTgp2l3XbADwmOMM5rpWZg",
            "alias": "disneys-oak-trail-golf-course-lake-buena-vista",
            "name": "Disney's Oak Trail Golf Course",
            "image_url": "https://s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/G3oE_KJJ53H1iweD-j83yQ/o.jpg",
            "is_closed": false,
            "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/disneys-oak-trail-golf-course-lake-buena-vista?adjust_creative=s-hyKAjsx6P4UW-uqMn7aQ&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=s-hyKAjsx6P4UW-uqMn7aQ",
            "review_count": 12,
            "categories": [
                {
                    "alias": "golf",
                    "title": "Golf"
                }
            ],
            "rating": 3.5,
            "coordinates": {
                "latitude": 28.4055855,
                "longitude": -81.5956011
            },
            "transactions": [],
            "location": {
                "address1": "1950 W Magnolia Palm Dr",
                "address2": "",
                "address3": "",
                "city": "Lake Buena Vista",
                "zip_code": "32836",
                "country": "US",
                "state": "FL",
                "display_address": [
                    "1950 W Magnolia Palm Dr",
                    "Lake Buena Vista, FL 32836"
                ]
            },
            "phone": "+14079394653",
            "display_phone": "(407) 939-4653",
            "distance": 3845.3340908128034
        },
        {
            "id": "VVF9h1jhhOVXIvxe-MDK8g",
            "alias": "panther-lake-golf-course-winter-garden",
            "name": "Panther Lake Golf Course",
            "image_url": "https://s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/ff47f9jXs56s3Cf7obIapA/o.jpg",
            "is_closed": false,
            "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/panther-lake-golf-course-winter-garden?adjust_creative=s-hyKAjsx6P4UW-uqMn7aQ&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=s-hyKAjsx6P4UW-uqMn7aQ",
            "review_count": 1,
            "categories": [
                {
                    "alias": "hotels",
                    "title": "Hotels"
                },
                {
                    "alias": "golf",
                    "title": "Golf"
                }
            ],
            "rating": 4.0,
            "coordinates": {
                "latitude": 28.4419223,
                "longitude": -81.6303836
            },
            "transactions": [],
            "location": {
                "address1": "16301 Phil Ritson Way",
                "address2": "",
                "address3": "",
                "city": "Winter Garden",
                "zip_code": "34787",
                "country": "US",
                "state": "FL",
                "display_address": [
                    "16301 Phil Ritson Way",
                    "Winter Garden, FL 34787"
                ]
            },
            "phone": "+14076562626",
            "display_phone": "(407) 656-2626",
            "distance": 1620.1533458028462
        },
        {
            "id": "UdqKnhBDg4b04e38qFcjEA",
            "alias": "orange-83-pub-and-grill-winter-garden",
            "name": "Orange 83 Pub And Grill",
            "image_url": "https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/KjWvn26iBv13GnIUCW7z9Q/o.jpg",
            "is_closed": false,
            "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/orange-83-pub-and-grill-winter-garden?adjust_creative=s-hyKAjsx6P4UW-uqMn7aQ&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=s-hyKAjsx6P4UW-uqMn7aQ",
            "review_count": 1,
            "categories": [
                {
                    "alias": "pubs",
                    "title": "Pubs"
                }
            ],
            "rating": 4.0,
            "coordinates": {
                "latitude": 28.4419223,
                "longitude": -81.6303836
            },
            "transactions": [],
            "location": {
                "address1": "16301 Phil Ritson Way",
                "address2": null,
                "address3": "Orange County National Golf Center & Lodge",
                "city": "Winter Garden",
                "zip_code": "34787",
                "country": "US",
                "state": "FL",
                "display_address": [
                    "16301 Phil Ritson Way",
                    "Orange County National Golf Center & Lodge",
                    "Winter Garden, FL 34787"
                ]
            },
            "phone": "+14076562626",
            "display_phone": "(407) 656-2626",
            "distance": 1620.1533458028462
        }
    ],
    "total": 3,
    "region": {
        "center": {
            "longitude": -81.6241764,
            "latitude": 28.4293403
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, note that at the top level of your JSON response there is an object `{ }` and not an array `[ ]`.

Which means you need to decode `BusinessesResponse` instead of `[RestaurantResponse]`:

```
let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(BusinessesResponse.self, from: d)
self.businesses = response.restaurants
```

Also note you're trying to decode `restaurants` and in the JSON response you have `businesses`. You can either rename your field inside `BusinessesResponse` to `restaurants` or, which might be *better*, use `CodingKeys`:

```
struct BusinessesResponse: Codable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case restaurants = "businesses"
    }

    let restaurants: [RestaurantResponse]
}
```

Also note you have `category` and `imageUrl` fields which don't exist in the JSON response. And the `categories` field in the JSON response is an *array* of *objects*.

Instead you can do:

```
struct RestaurantResponse: Codable, Identifiable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, name, is_closed, categories, url, review_count, rating, display_phone, distance
        case imageURL = "image_url"
    }

    ...
    var categories: [RestaurantCategory]
    var imageURL: URL
    ...
}

struct RestaurantCategory: Codable {
    var alias: String
    var title: String
}
```

If you decide to use `CodingKeys` then you can also change your other variables: `is_closed`, `review_count` to *camelCase*.

Alternatively if all your variables in the model will be the *camelCase* equivalents of the *snake_case* keys in the JSON response you can use:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
```

Comment: Using the above struct for RestaurantCategory to access the nested array of information in the JSON response, how would I go about displaying that in a text view?  Text(restaurant.title) isn't working, but obviously I'm wrong in using that.

Comment: `var categories: [RestaurantCategory]` is a collection of elements which means one restaurant can have multiple categories. Which do you want to display? If the first one, you can do `restaurant.categories[0].title` (assuming `categories` is not empty).

Comment: Thanks that answered my question. Ideally, I plan to display all the categories, but I can put an if statement on it to control if it displays. Thank you for the help, I appreciate it.

Comment: You can display all categories in one `Text` view or have multiple views in a `ForEach`. But I recommend you create a new question where you can specify exactly how you want to display your categories. I'll be happy to help you there.